# CSS Styling Issues

Tags: html, css

Code:

```
<style>
    .RoundButton
    {
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 34px;
      width: 70px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border-radius: 15px;
      -moz-border-radius: 15px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
      border: 5px solid #000000;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    .RoundButton:link {color: #000000;}
    .RoundButton:visited {color: #000000;}
    .RoundButton:hover {color: #000000;border: 5px solid #ff0000;}
    .RoundButton:active {color: #000000; border: 5px solid #0000ff;}
</style>
```

Then I have some HTML:

```
<center><a href="https://www.google.com" target="blank"><div class="RoundButton">Hi</div></a></center>
```

When I view it it shows the default link colors, but the round button changing color
works. I looked on W3Schools, and their example looks like mine, but works. Help?

Comment: Do you have an opening style tag?  It should,t be changing colors at all, with the styles you have.

Comment: lol yes i just missed that in the copypaste...

Comment: @MatthewJohnson The tags were being eaten in the markup, fixed now.

Comment: and the border changes color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make your question more specific. What is the issue on your styling?

Comment: well i want the link to change color, but it doesn't and even with the `text-decoration: none` it still is underlined.

Comment: Works fine. have you declared class="RoundButton" in you <a> tag?

Comment: No I declared it in the div tag.

Comment: Declare it inside <a> tag and it will work because you styled it as a link.

Comment: if you want to declare it inside a div use a ">" or a pointer to point it to its child. Example: .RoundButton > a:link {color: #000000;}

Answer (score 0):

Then change the .RoundButton:hover to a:hover {} to what ever you like.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML:

```
<div class="RoundButton"><a href="https://www.google.com" target="blank">Hi</a></div>
```

The CSS

```
.RoundButton
{
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 34px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  border: 5px solid #000000;
  padding: 5px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.RoundButton:hover {color: #000000;border: 5px solid #ff0000;}
.RoundButton:active {color: #000000; border: 5px solid #0000ff;}
a:link {color: #000000;}
a:visited {color: #000000;}
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/5cJK5/).

I centered the div using `margin:0 auto` instead of the `<center>` tag, and adjusted the CSS.